# How to get the selected value from a DDL on an aspx page to an MVC View field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following dropdownlist (ddl) in an aspx page

```
                                <div class="inputContent">
                                <div class="input-container">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAlternateLot_ID" runat="server" dtrequired="0" dtfieldtype="numeric"
                                        onchange="popup_AlternateLotChannel();">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

What I am attempting to do is to get the selected value of this ddl into the controller of a new MVC page.  I tried the following and got an error

```
            string strDDLValue = Request.Form["ddlAlternateLot_ID"].ToString();
        vm.AltLocation = strDDLValue;
```

I kind of took for granted that it was not referencing the "form" name of the aspx page which is _inventory_detail.aspx.  But I am not sure if that is the culprit or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a popup dialog? from the naming of the change handler, the easiest way to do that is have the ok button of the dialog redirect to your MVC controller method with the parameter value. So you would redirect to a url like [site]/[controller]/[action]/[parametervalue] that will pass the value to the controller if you are using the default routing in MVC

Comment: The popup only happens if they select "Add New" in the drop down so if they do that this would work perfectly.

Comment: Ok, so change your change function to redirect if its a value other than new, and popup the dialog, if its add new.